# Accessing parent scope from directive

Tags: html, angular.js, scope

This is how I can access the exact scope value, otherwise it will be `$scope.type` of local scope.

I am accessing this from the template in `NSPopover`. `NSPopover` directive has `scope: true`.

It's also inside the Angular bootstrap module.

```
<label ng-class="{selected: $parent.$parent.$parent.type == current.type}" >
    <input type="radio" name="type" ng-value="current.type" ng-change="chooseOption()" ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.type"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `$parent` is an anti-pattern and sign of bad architecture. What if you code changes together with your parent chain - it will instantly break your code.

Also, have you thought about how you are going to test it?

---

To have a clean readable code, you want someone looking at it immediately see the meaning. What is the meaning of this object? -

```
ng-model = "$parent.$parent.$parent.type"
```

Would you not rather see

```
ng-model = "selectedItem"
```

or something more concrete like

```
ng-model = "myCar"
```

---

Naming something "current" makes me wonder what it is. From your code, I have no idea, so it forces me to spend time on looking around and getting clues, for what should be made clear right up front.

Comment: well, I know it's anti-pattern that's why I am asking. its' the model `booking.type`. But the problem is that I cannot watch changes of just model `booking.type` as it's inside another scope, created by `NSPopover` and angular modal. How to change that?

Comment: @vickk You can either used shared services (preferred) or events.